# Are there performance implications in creating a common object constructor?

Tags: c#, performance

## Background

Let's say I have an `Address` object:

```
public class Address_Model{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Street{get; set;}
     public string City {get; set;}
     public string State {get; set;}
     public string PostalCode{get; set;}
}
```

This property is used in several other objects (i.e `office` object, `home` object, etc):

```
public class Office_Model{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public Address_Model Address{get; set;}
     //. . . (other properties specific to the office model)
}

public class Home_Model{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public Address_Model Address{get; set;}
     //. . . (other properties specific to the home model)
}
```

These models live in my BLL.  In my constructor, which uses data from my DAL, I currently construct the `Address` property manually:

```
public Office_Model GetOffice(int id){

var office = DAL.SomeClass.GettOfficeById(id);

return new Office_Model
{
   Id = office.Id,
   Address = new Address_Model{
       Id = office.Address.Id,
       Street = office.Address.Street,
       City = office.Address.City,
       State = office.Address.State,
       PostalCode = office.Address.PostalCode
   }
}

}

public Home_Model GetHome(int id){

var home = DAL.SomeClass.GettHomeById(id);

return new Home_Model
{
   Id = home.Id,
   Address = new Address_Model{
       Id = home.Address.Id,
       Street = home.Address.Street,
       City = home.Address.City,
       State = home.Address.State,
       PostalCode = home.Address.PostalCode
   }
}

}
```

In order to increase code maintainability (e.g. not having to add a new property like `Street2` to all places where an `Address_Model` is constructed), I would like to create a common method to construct an address model:

```
public Address_Model GetAddressModel(DAL.SomeClass.Address address){

     return new Address_Model{
           Id = address.Address.Id,
           Street = address.Address.Street,
           City = address.Address.City,
           State = address.Address.State,
           PostalCode = address.Address.PostalCode
     }

}
```

Now my BLL getter methods look more like this:

```
  public Office_Model GetOffice(int id){

    var office = DAL.SomeClass.GettOfficeById(id);

    return new Office_Model
    {
       Id = office.Id,
       Address = GetAddressModel(office.Address);
    }

    }

    public Home_Model GetHome(int id){

    var home = DAL.SomeClass.GettHomeById(id);

    return new Home_Model
    {
       Id = home.Id,
       Address = GetAddressModel(home.Address);
    }

    }
```

## Question

Will delegating this construction operation have negative performance implications?  I am new to performance profiling and have just learned about `boxing` and `unboxing`; I am not sure if that type of performance degradation will apply to what I am doing here.

Obviously, I have simplified this example to a great degree.  In reality there would be many more nested objects that need constructing.

Comment: Please read: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: You can mostly ignore nearly all performance considerations during initial development and then address any such issues that you explicitly measure once your application is fully working.

Comment: There's no boxing going on here. And no, this will not affect performance.

Comment: @Cameron: Thanks, that's all I needed to know.

Comment: Once you get a chance to really play with performance profiling, you may discover something interesting; in my experience, the bottleneck is almost never where I thought it would be.

Comment: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil" ~~ D. Knuth

Comment: @KrisVandermotten--That is an entertaining read, and I get the point.  My concern is more around developing good habits from the start rather than trying to improve an application in hindsight.  I realize this isn't always possible.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg--I just laughed at the phrase `premature optimization` a little more than I should have.

Comment: Of course it could affect performance, you've added a method call where there was not one before.  You have to decide if that performance increase is important.  1 extra call a day?  1 extra call every 20 ms?  Measure then decide.  Keep in mind, one extra method calls is likely on the order of nanoseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Boxing`, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx):

> Boxing is the process of converting a **value type** to the type object or
>   to any interface type implemented by this value type.

As your `Address` object is a reference type (marked as a `class` and not a `struct`), and you expect to receive a `Address` type as an argument, there will be no boxing occuring in your code. More so, the JIT compiler may decide to inline your method call, which will eliminate creating a new stack frame for that call all together.

Comment: Sure. As a side note, i would consider refactoring those methods so you wouldn't have to add this method at all. Look into http://www.automapper.org, may make your life easier.